# Asterisk 11, Queue & Local channel state

Tags: asterisk

I'm using a queue in asterisk 11:

```
CLI> core show version
Asterisk 11.13.1~dfsg-2+b1 built by buildd @ brahms on a x86_64 running Linux on 2015-01-05 21:34:10 UTC
```

But when the member has answered the call, the member is not mark as "Inuse"

What i'd like to do is:
 - Store in asterisk internal database real member extension
 - Member will be dialed with a "fake" extension number with a LocalChannel (like Local/001@test-queue-member) which will get real member extension from database
 - Play a annoucement to that member
 - Do some stuff when the member answered (like logging)

first of all, the member extension:

```
[999]
username=999
Callerid="999" <999>
secret=0999
context=test-queue-ctx
type=friend
language=fr
host=dynamic
dtmfmode=RFC2833
dtmfmode=info
qualify=yes
nat=yes
canreinvite=no
insecure=invite,port
call-limit=1
callcounter=yes
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
```

next the queue conf:

```
[test-queue]
music=blank
strategy=rrmemory
timeout=9
retry=1
wrapuptime=2
maxlen=0
announce-frequency=0
announce-holdtime=no
ringinuse=no
setinterfacevar=yes
setqueueentryvar=yes
setqueuevar=yes
eventwhencalled=yes
eventmemberstatus=yes
autofill=no
```

And here the dial plan:

```
[test-queue-ctx]
exten => _X.,1,Noop()
    same => n,Ringing()
    ;; Queue options
    ;;      c: continue in the dialplan if the callee hangs up
    ;;      i: ignore call forward requests from queue members and do nothing when they are requested
    ;;      r: ring instead of playing MOH
    ;;      R: stops moh and rings once an agent is ringing
    ;;      h: allow callee to hang up by pressing *.
    ;;      H: allow caller to hang up by pressing *.
    same => n,Queue(test-queue,cirRhH,,,300,,,test-announce)
    same => n,NoOp("Dialstatus=${DIALSTATUS}")

[test-announce]
exten => s,1,NoOp()
    same => n,Playback(hello-world)
    same => n,Return()

[test-queue-member]
exten => _X.,1,NoOp(Dialling ${EXTEN})
    same => n,Macro(test-queue-dial,${EXTEN})

[macro-test-queue-dial]
exten => s,1,NoOp(Dialling ARG1=${ARG1})
    same => n,GotoIf($["${DB(AGENT/${ARG1}/PHONE)}" != ""]?dial,1:dial-NOPHONE,1)

exten => dial,1,NoOp(AgentDial,agent_id: ${ARG1},phone: ${DB(AGENT/${ARG1}/PHONE)})
    same => n,Dial(SIP/${DB(AGENT/${ARG1}/PHONE)},10,rotwhgU(test-queue-answer^${ARG1}))  ; Ring the interface, 10 seconds maximum
    same => n,NoOp("DialStatus=${DIALSTATUS}")
    same => n,GotoIf($[${DIALSTATUS} != "ANSWER"]?dial-${DIALSTATUS},1)
exten => dial-NOANSWER,1,Hangup()
exten => dial-BUSY,1,Busy()
exten => dial-CHANUNAVAIL,1,Hangup()
exten => dial-CONGESTION,1,Congestion()
exten => dial-NOPHONE,1,Hangup()

[test-queue-answer]
exten => s,1,NoOp("test-queue-answer")
    same => n,Return()
```

And finally i add member to the queue in asterisk CLI:

```
CLI> database put AGENT/001 PHONE 999
CLI> queue add member Local/001@test-queue-member to test-queue
```

---

But when i do this, when a user call, enter the queue and the member answer, member is not "InUse", and there is "No callers"

```
CLI> queue show test-queue
test-queue has 0 calls (max unlimited) in 'rrmemory' strategy (1s holdtime, 3s talktime), W:0, C:1, A:5, SL:0.0% within 0s
   Members: 
      Local/001@test-queue-member (ringinuse disabled) (dynamic) (Not in use) has taken 1 calls (last was 916 secs ago)
   No Callers
```

How i can fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Before do your own "pet queues" it is nice idea read how it should be, for example in freepbx.org source code/dialplan.

If you want have state, you should use channel with state or do state manually via hints. Local channel not designed for one-line connection so have no state.

For more info about hints see this page https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Extension+State+and+Hints